# Programmatically create a discount code

Tags: 8, commerce

Does anyone know how to programmatically create a discount code in Drupal  Commerce?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to always review the tests. The tests create promotions and coupons programmatically.

Here's how to create a promotion.

```
$promotion = Promotion::create([
  'name' => 'Promotion test',
  'order_types' => ['default'],
  'stores' => [$this->store->id()],
  'offer' => [
    'target_plugin_id' => 'order_percentage_off',
    'target_plugin_configuration' => [
      'amount' => '0.10',
    ],
  ],
  'start_date' => '2017-01-01',
  'status' => TRUE,
]);
$promotion->save();
```

And then coupons.

```
$coupon = Coupon::create([
  'promotion_id' => $promotion->id(),
  'code' => 'coupon_code',
  'usage_limit' => 1,
  'status' => TRUE,
]);
$coupon->save();
```

Comment: Yeah thanks. I would up just writing my own class to do it. It was a bit more complicated than that but thats good to know for future reference.